# hide bootstrap modal after select redirect instead

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to close my modalbox, so I return to the same page, after I click the "Select" button.

I am on `shuffle.php`. I open the modalbox and call the code in `updaterecords.php`. When I click Select I should return to `shuffle.php`. The problem is right now that I am redirected to `updaterecords.php`.

I try to solve that with adding this code to my AJAX call:

```
$('#editBox').on('hide.bs.modal', function (data) {
   $('#editBox').modal('hide')
})
```

But I am still redirected. Is the code I added in the wrong place?

**shuffle.php**

```
<div class="modal-footer msg">
  <form action="updaterecords.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="fantasy-id" value="" name="id" />
    <button type="submit" name="selectStore" >Select</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**updaterecords.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-open-modal").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'getdata.php',
      data: {
        post_id: id
      }, 
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jdata) {
          console.log("is json");
          $("#editBox").modal().show();
          $('#id').val(jdata.id);
          $("#editBox .modal-title").html(jdata.headline);
          $("#editBox .modal-body").html("Weekday: " + jdata.weekday + "<br><br>Description: " + jdata.description); //  + " " + $query $query => query

          $('#editBox').on('hide.bs.modal', function (data) {
            $('#editBox').modal('hide')
          })

        } else {
          console.log("not valid json: " + data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `$('.modal').modal('hide');` on updaterecords.php.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-open-modal").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'getdata.php',
      data: {
        post_id: id
      }, 
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
        if (jdata) {
          console.log("is json");
          $("#editBox").modal().show();
          $('#id').val(jdata.id);
          $("#editBox .modal-title").html(jdata.headline);
          $("#editBox .modal-body").html("Weekday: " + jdata.weekday + "<br><br>Description: " + jdata.description); //  + " " + $query $query => query

          $('#editBox').on('hide.bs.modal', function (data) {
            $('#editBox').modal('hide')
          })

        } else {
          console.log("not valid json: " + data);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not do anything in my code unfortually.